# Export HTML table from an iframe to CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, html-table

I'm trying to look for a script (with no progess) that could export an HTML table that I am able to get from an iframe. The table is inside the iframe and I can get and display its contents on my parent document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var myIFrame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("table").innerHTML;
    alert(content);
    // suggestions here to export the table to CSV
   }
</script>
```

I am not asking you to write the code for me. I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Have you ever tried datatables? It provides support for exporting. http://datatables.net/ Here is the export example https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/exportButtons.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple jsfiddle to illustrate the idea. https://jsfiddle.net/anjvsqt7/9/

The code snippet from the example I made is below:

```
var csvStr = '';

var table = $('#table');
var rows = table.children('tbody').children('tr');
var len = rows.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    var row = $(rows[i]);
    var cols = row.children('td');
    for(var j=0;j<cols.length;j++) {
        col = cols[j];
        csvStr += col.innerText + ',';
    }
    csvStr += '\n';
}

//console.log(csvStr);
```

Comment: Hi John! I tried your suggestion by trying to output each cell but it's not working. Does it matter if the table rows and cells are inside another table with a "tbody" tag? Thanks for this!

Comment: You are right!  I made a mistake, good catch.  I updated the example with that correction.

Answer (score 0):

I have used datatables to do this in the past.

It gives you options to display buttons that can be used to export to CSV, Excel and PDF as well as exporting to your clipboard.

[Example page](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/exportButtons.html)